# Concurrent partial updates in Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-java, concurrentmodification

Consider the following mongo document

```
{
  _id:...
  param1:oldValue1
  param2:oldValue2 
}
```

Suppose if am trying to do two concurrent partial updates with the following queries:

```
db.collection.update(  { _id:...} , { $set: { param1 : "newValue1"  } }
db.collection.update(  { _id:...} , { $set: { param2 : "newValue2"  } }
```

Will I get the following docuemnt state in mongo after these concurrent partial updates:

```
{
  _id:...
  param1:newValue1
  param2:newValue2
}
```

Does two concurrent updates leave the document with updated values considering the fact that the concurrent updates dont have common fields.without concurrent modification issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, regardless of the execution order of the two updates, the doc will end up as you show it.  This is because the two atomic `$set` operations target distinct fields, and any field not referenced in the update isn't modified.